# PostgreSQL: WHERE ID IN file_with_ids

Tags: postgresql

I have a file with ids which looks like this:

```
10555
16452
17005
17511
17512
17513
17515
17516
17517
17518
17520
17521
17522
17523
17524
17525
```

This file was created with unix tools like `grep` and `cut`.

I would like to execute a SQL statement in PostgreSQL roughly like this:

```
SELECT * from my_table where id in file_with_ids;
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You need to import that file into a temporary table, e.g. using `copy´

Comment: Does the file exist on the database machine, or the client machine?  Are you trying to do this simply one time, or make it simple to incorporate it into a workflow which will be recurring?  And how many entries in that file?

Comment: @jjanes I have the file on the client machine. I need this from time to time in different situations. If it would happen often in the same situation, then I would use Python and Django (we use django orm and just for debugging or special stuff psql). There are 5 up to 5k entries in the file.

Answer (score 3):

As *a_horse_with_no_name*'s suggestion, the first step you need a CSV file that stores `ids`. Then, import it to database and execute your query as below

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_list_ids (id int);
COPY tmp_list_ids FROM 'your absolute path here' CSV; 
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id IN (SELECT t.id FROM tmp_list_ids);
```

Please note that the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html) command is only allowed to superuser (**bold is mine**)

> **Files named in a COPY command are read or written directly by the
>   server**, not by the client application. Therefore, they must reside on
>   or be accessible to the database server machine, not the client. They
>   must be accessible to and readable or writable by the PostgreSQL user
>   (the user ID the server runs as), not the client ...
>   COPY naming a file or **command is only allowed to database superusers**
>   or users who are granted one of the default roles
>   pg_read_server_files, pg_write_server_files, or
>   pg_execute_server_program, since it allows reading or writing any file
>   or running a program that the server has privileges to access.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is on the client machine, and the list is not in the hundreds of thousands long, I would just use the client-side programming language to read the file and package them up and incorporate them into the query itself.  In python with psycopg2, I believe the prefered way to do this would be by binding a python array/list to a postgresql array and using "=ANY" rather than "IN":

```
cursor.execute(cursor.mogrify(
    "select * from pgbench_accounts where aid =ANY (%s)", (py_array,)
))
```

If the file were on the server side, then the [file_fdw extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) seems like a good option, the you could populate the in-list with a subselect, or rewrite the query into a join.  You might even be able to use "program" rather than "filename" and incorporate  the grep and cut into that, if you want the pipeline to be re-executed each time the query is invoked, rather than running it once and memorizing the result.  One caveat is that you can't ANALYZE a file_fdw table, like you can a regular table you load with COPY, so you might not get optimal query plans.